# Convert a comma separated list of values within a postgres table column to be used within an in clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Within a postgres table called `all_fruits`, I have the following text column data stored, that a comma separated:

Column fruit_name = `apples, oranges, pears`

I would like to use this column data as part of a select IN query, i.e.:

```
select countries
from   all_countries
where  fruit in (select fruit_name from all_fruits where fruit_id = 123);
```

My question is, how can I in postgres convert this comma separated list of fruits (`fruit_name`) to appear as follows with single quotes around each individual fruit name:

Column fruit_name = `'apples', 'oranges', 'pears'` so that I can use in above `IN` clause?

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to normalize your data model an not store comma separated values.

But if you can't fix your model, you need to unnest the values:

```
select countries
from all_countries
where fruit in (select f.name 
                from all_fruits af
                  cross join unnest(string_to_array(af.fruit_name, ',')) as f(name)
                where af.fruit_id = 123
               )
```

Comment: Just realised that I also need to filter within the in clause query and so need a `where` condition. I tried `where fruit_id = 123` prior to cross join, but didn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming that adding a `where` condition within your cross join unset is not possible?

Comment: @ArthurJ: that's possible, just like with any other (sub)select

Comment: I actually tried it as mentioned and it didn't like it.